# Find total count of selected item using checkbox in android (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

I have some **Checkbox** (suppose 5) and one **Button**. When I clicked in the button, I want to show a toast message with total selected checkbox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

according to your question this could possibly be the answer to your question. hope this helps..if you could provide more information about your requirement we could help in much better way

```
private CheckBox one, two, three, four, five;// checkboxes you want
Button btn;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

    one=findViewById(R.id.one);
    two=findViewById(R.id.two);
    three=findViewById(R.id.three);
    four=findViewById(R.id.four);
    five=findViewById(R.id.five);
    btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);


    one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isCheckedOrNot(isChecked);
        }
    });
    two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isCheckedOrNot(isChecked);
        }
    });
    three.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isCheckedOrNot(isChecked);
        }
    });
    four.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isCheckedOrNot(isChecked);
        }
    });
    five.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isCheckedOrNot(isChecked);
        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count + " checkbox checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void isCheckedOrNot(boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        count++;
    } else {
        if (count > 0) {
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
rb = findViewById(R.id.rb); // make 5 of them
int x=0;

        rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // make 5 of them
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();
                // Check which radiobutton was pressed
                if (checked){
                    x++;
                    }
                }

            }
        });


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         System.out.println(x);
        }
      });
```